# Include frequencies of missing values using apply() and table()

Tags: r, lapply

I have a simple matrix and apply a function to calculate frequencies:

```
testM <- matrix(c(rep(1,3), rep(0,3)), ncol = 2, byrow = T)

> testM
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    1    0
[3,]    0    0

r <- apply(testM, 1, function(x) { table(x) })
```

After applying I have a list of tables

```
x Frq  x.1 F.1 x.2 F.2
1   2   0   1   0   2 
1   2   1   1   0   2
```

This result is read taking pairs of columns. As you can see, the table() function doesn't "guess" that I am only counting 0's and 1's, and puts another 1 with frequency 2 (or another 0 with frq 2) where I expected

```
x Frq  x.1 F.1 x.2 F.2
1   2   0   1   1   0 
0   0   1   1   0   2
```

Any ideas or better solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to convert each `vector` to `factor` with `levels` specified

```
apply(testM, 1, function(x)  table(factor(x, levels=0:1)) )
```